# How to show variable in Golang template inside range

Tags: go, templates, go-gin

I have some code on the server:

```
c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "videos.html", gin.H{
    "files": files, //slice
    "errMessage": errMessage,
})
```

And I have some code on the client:

```
{{ range .files }}
<tr>
  <td>{{.}}</td>
  <td><a href="/download?filename={{.}}" style="color:blue;">Download</a></td>
  <td><a href="/delete?filename={{.}}" style="color:red;">Delete</a></td>
  <td><button id="{{.}}">Посмотреть</button></td>
  {{ if .errMessage }} <td style="color:red;">Processing...</td>
  {{ else }} <td>Done</td> {{ end }}
</tr>
{{ end }}
```

How to deal with .errMessage?

Comment: `$.errMessage`. From the docs: *" When execution begins, $ is set to the data argument passed to Execute, that is, to the starting value of dot. "*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you show what is the error message? I deduce that your `.errMessage` is out of scope inside your `{{ range .files }}` syntax.

So to fix this problem, you will just declare your `.errMessage` on top of your `{{ range .files }}` syntax.

Though its not necessary to declare it on top, the main key here is that you should assign your `.errMessage` to another variable inside of your template.

It would look something like this ( based on your example ):

```
...
{{ $errMessage := .errMessage }}

{{ range .files }}
<tr>
  <td>{{.}}</td>
  <td><a href="/download?filename={{.}}" style="color:blue;">Download</a></td>
  <td><a href="/delete?filename={{.}}" style="color:red;">Delete</a></td>
  <td><button id="{{.}}">Посмотреть</button></td>
  {{ if $errMessage }} <td style="color:red;">Processing...</td>
  {{ else }} <td>Done</td> {{ end }}
</tr>
{{ end }}
...
```

Hope that helps! Cheers!